# Add-on in Google docs or others to provide functionality in App Maker

Tags: google-docs, google-app-maker

Can you create an add-on in google docs or any other google app that can access an app in App Maker to make changes in the app via the add-on?

Comment: Not at this time. There is no API as of this moment to access App Maker from another Google Service or from an external service. However, if you are just interested in making changes to data that is served using app maker, then you can use the JCDB service via apps script and connect to the Cloud SQL instance that your app maker app is connected to.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusMalessa. I will try this